# How to display category name from commenter's custom post

Tags: comments, categories

I have this code that displays the commenter's post title. I'd like to display the post category instead. I've tried every permatation of post_title to try to display the category, but with no luck.

```
<?php 
$args = array(
'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),    
'author' => $comment->user_id,
'orderby' => 'post_date',
'order' => 'ASC',
'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$comment_author_posts = get_posts( $args );
if ($comment_author_posts):
foreach ( $comment_author_posts as $comment_author_post ): ?>
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $comment_author_post->ID ) ?>"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<?php echo $comment_author_post->post_title ?></a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`get_the_category`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/)

This can be done by either using `setup_postdata( $comment_author_post )` or by passing the post ID using `$comment_author_post->ID`

**USING setup_postdata()**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
    'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
    'author' => $comment->user_id,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$comment_author_posts = get_posts( $args );
if ($comment_author_posts):
    foreach ( $comment_author_posts as $comment_author_post ):
        setup_postdata( $comment_author_post );
        $categories = get_the_category();
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $comment_author_post->ID ) ?>"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <?php echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name ); ?></a>

        <?php
    endforeach;
endif;
```

**USING $comment_author_post->ID**

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => array( 'post' ),
    'post_status' => array( 'publish' ),
    'author' => $comment->user_id,
    'orderby' => 'post_date',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 1
);
$comment_author_posts = get_posts( $args );
if ($comment_author_posts):
    foreach ( $comment_author_posts as $comment_author_post ):
        $categories = get_the_category( $comment_author_post->ID );
        ?>
        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $comment_author_post->ID ) ?>"><i class="fa fa-users" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <?php echo esc_html( $categories[0]->name ); ?></a>

        <?php
    endforeach;
endif;
```

> **References**
>
> [`get_posts()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/)
>
> [`get_the_category()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_category/)